# Project Euler #11 Java implementation

Tags: java, programming-challenge, mathematics

Project Euler 11  Solution in Java.
The problem is at https://projecteuler.net/problem=11

```java
package coderbyte;

public class Java {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int Grid[][] = {
                { 8, 02, 22, 97, 38, 15, 00, 40, 00, 75, 04, 05, 07, 78, 52,
                        12, 50, 77, 91, 8 },
                { 49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69,
                        48, 04, 56, 62, 00 },
                { 81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30,
                        03, 49, 13, 36, 65 },
                { 52, 70, 95, 23, 04, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 01, 32, 56,
                        71, 37, 02, 36, 91 },
                { 22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40,
                        28, 66, 33, 13, 80 },
                { 24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 03, 45, 02, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84,
                        20, 35, 17, 12, 50 },
                { 32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70,
                        66, 18, 38, 64, 70 },
                { 67, 26, 20, 68, 02, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8, 40,
                        91, 66, 49, 94, 21 },
                { 24, 55, 58, 05, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14,
                        88, 34, 89, 63, 72 },
                { 21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 00, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 00, 61, 33,
                        97, 34, 31, 33, 95 },
                { 78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 03, 80, 04, 62, 16,
                        14, 9, 53, 56, 92 },
                { 16, 39, 05, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 00, 17, 54,
                        24, 36, 29, 85, 57 },
                { 86, 56, 00, 48, 35, 71, 89, 07, 05, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21,
                        58, 51, 54, 17, 58 },
                { 19, 80, 81, 68, 05, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17,
                        77, 04, 89, 55, 40 },
                { 04, 52, 8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 07, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26,
                        79, 33, 27, 98, 66 },
                { 88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 03, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12,
                        32, 63, 93, 53, 69 },
                { 04, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8, 46, 29,
                        32, 40, 62, 76, 36 },
                { 20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59,
                        85, 74, 04, 36, 16 },
                { 20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 01, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81,
                        16, 23, 57, 05, 54 },
                { 01, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52,
                        01, 89, 19, 67, 48 } };

        int currentHorizProduct = 1;
        int currentVertiProduct = 1;
        int currentDiag1Product = 1;
        int currentDiag2Product = 1;

        // Horizontally

        for (int row = 0; row < Grid.length; row++) {
            int product = 1;
            int counter = 0;
            for (int column = 0; column < Grid[row].length; column++) {

                product = Grid[row][column] * product;
                counter++;
                if (counter == 4) {
                    if (currentHorizProduct < product) {
                        currentHorizProduct = product;
                    }
                    if (Grid[row][column - 3] == 0) {
                        product = Grid[row][column] * Grid[row][column - 1]
                                * Grid[row][column - 2];
                    } else {
                        product = product / Grid[row][column - 3];
                    }
                    counter = 3;
                }

            }
        }

        System.out.println(currentHorizProduct);

        // Vertically

        for (int row = 0; row < Grid.length; row++) {
            int product = 1;
            int counter = 0;
            for (int column = 0; column < Grid[row].length; column++) {

                product = Grid[column][row] * product;
                counter++;
                if (counter == 4) {
                    if (currentVertiProduct < product) {
                        currentVertiProduct = product;
                    }
                    if (Grid[column - 3][row] == 0) {
                        product = Grid[column][row] * Grid[column - 1][row]
                                * Grid[column - 2][row];
                    } else {
                        product = product / Grid[column - 3][row];
                    }
                    counter = 3;
                }

            }
        }

        System.out.println(currentVertiProduct);

        // Diagonally right

        for (int row = 0; row <= Grid.length - 4; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column <= Grid[row].length - 4; column++) {

                int product = Grid[row][column] * Grid[row + 1][column + 1]
                        * Grid[row + 2][column + 2] * Grid[row + 3][column + 3];

                if (currentDiag1Product < product) {
                    currentDiag1Product = product;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(currentDiag1Product);

        // Diagonally left

        for (int row = 0; row < Grid.length - 3; row++) {
            for (int column = 3; column < Grid[row].length; column++) {

                int product = Grid[row][column] * Grid[row + 1][column - 1]
                        * Grid[row + 2][column - 2] * Grid[row + 3][column - 3];

                if (currentDiag2Product < product) {
                    currentDiag2Product = product;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(currentDiag2Product);

        System.out.println("Max result is : "
                + Math.max(Math.max(currentVertiProduct, currentHorizProduct),
                        Math.max(currentDiag1Product, currentDiag2Product)));

    }
}
```

Any tips on how to improve the "Diagonal" part.... and probably shorten the code....

Answer (score 3):

You're doing all of the different kinds of products independently. That's a **lot** of code duplication, and ends up hiding what the goal of the project is.

We want to find the max product. That suggests the following structure:

```
int best = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < Grid.length; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < Grid[row].length; ++col) {
        best = Math.max(best, productAt(Grid, row, col));
    }
}

System.out.println("Max result is : " + best)
```

Okay, that's pretty simple. We just have a double loop looking for `best`. That just leaves `productAt()`. That's a function that takes the starting point and returns the largest possible product starting from there. Once you reduce the problem to just one source point, then it's not so bad:

```
int productAtIter(int [][] Grid, int row, int col, int drow, int dcol)
{
    if (row + 3 * drow >= 0 && row + 3 * drow < Grid.length &&
        col + 3 * drow >= 0 && col + 3 * drow < Grid[row].length)
    {
        int prod = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            prod *= Grid[row + i * drow][col + i * dcol];
        }
        return prod;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int productAt(int[][] Grid, int row, int col)
{
    best = 0;

    // horizontal
    best = Math.max(best, productAtIter(Grid, row, col, +1, 0);

    // vertical
    best = Math.max(best, productAtIter(Grid, row, col, 0, +1);

    // diagonal-right
    best = Math.max(best, productAtIter(Grid, row, col, +1, +1);

    // diagonal-left
    best = Math.max(best, productAtIter(Grid, row, col, +1, -1);

    return best;
}
```